# In iPhone 6+ gmail app email template is not responsive, else everywhere it is working fine

Tags: gmail, html-email, responsive

I am having an issue with iPhone 6+ Gmail app in that particular device I am getting a responsive issue, my email template is not responsive in that device else everywhere it is working fine. can you please help in this condition

Comment: Can you post your code, please?

Comment: https://codepen.io/Sam_pandit/pen/wpYpLo
please check here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working now
use
@media only screen and (max-width:667px) {

.scale {
    width: 90%!important;
    float: none!important
}
}

Comment: https://codepen.io/shahilparichay/pen/jOmgxBv   use this email template for refrence